# Determine if Activity came to front due to back navigation

Tags: android, android-activity, back, onresume

I'd like to know if my Activity was displayed because the user pressed back
on some other Activity. In the Lifecycle I couldn't identify any Callbacks
that are robustly giving me that info.

`onRestart()` is not working. It will also fire if the Apps Task was brought to front.
`onResume()` will not work for the same reason.

I suppose there is a simple solution for that, but in Android supposedly simple things can be pretty nasty.

Comment: study [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10493384/779408)

Comment: This a little bit late, but why doesn't onRestart work? It works for me?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Call your 2nd activity with `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)`, then override the `onBackPressed()` in the 2nd activity and have it `setResult()` to `RESULT_CANCELED`.  Lastly, have the 1st activity catch that in `onActivityResult()`.

**Code example:**

Activity 1:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

---

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user pressed back from 2nd activity to go to 1st activity. code here
        }
    }
}
```

Activity 2:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: good answer, though I have around 15 Activities and I am using AndoridAnnotations which has no option for calling startActivityForResult (yet, though in an upcoming release)... so I am still hoping for some other idea...

Comment: Does AndroidAnnotations prevent you from using normal, basic Android constructs like this one? I wouldn't use such a tool then...

Comment: No I can use standard android constructs, but I already have 15 Activities that i have to touch now. The answer might just be "the way to do it".

Comment: If the user presses back, the result code passed in to onActivityResult() will NOT be RESULT_OK (unless you do some other monkeying around). You don't need to touch any of the 15 callable activities - just test for (resultCode != RESULT_OK).