# Is there something like Clear Bottom in Intent Flag?

Tags: android

Activity A is the home page of my application.

```
A -> B -> C
```

C starts A with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP to get the home page A correctly. This works fine and the stack simply becomes,

```
A
```

But B can be invoked directly using Notification Manager.

```
B -> C -> A
```

So even I use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag while starting A in C, the B and C still exists in Stack before A(home page) and on pressing back button from A, it goes back to B and C.

I dont want this behavior. On starting activity A from C, The stack only should have A. How canI do this?

Comment: you can close it using activity results, or just call `finish()` when you no longer want it, aka when exiting B.

Comment: If I need to finish, then I have to finish both B and C so that pressing back on A will return to Android Home. But I dont want to finish B on starting C because I need C to go back to B using back button.

Comment: Then use activity result. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html That way you can chain close a set of activities, if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about navigation, you can define both B and C as [android:noHistory](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist)

BTW. I asked at some moment kind-of related question. You may be intresting to take a look at it:
[How to always start from a startup activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451171/how-to-always-start-from-a-startup-activity-on-android)

Comment: No. I need to go back from C to B on pressing back button. I will look on your thread.

Comment: Take a look at FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK) . You can se this flag and it will clear the task (all activities in the stack)

Comment: @VictorRonin `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` is only available from API level 11 (Android 3.0)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you start `ActivityA` (instead of `ActivityB`) from the notification, since you obviously want that activity to always be the root activity in your task. Add an extra to the `Intent` that gets passed to the `Notification`. Then, in `onCreate()` of `ActivityA`, you should check if the extra is present and if so, immediately start `ActivityB`. This should give you the navigation behaviour that you want.